# None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: inAppPurchase

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I have working application in AppStore. It has inApp Purchases.

Certificate and provision profile was expired.

I updated it, but XCode wrote:

**"Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: inAppPurchase.."**

I pressed "Fix Issue Automatically",  XCode wrote

**"An App ID with identifier 'com.mycompany.myproj' is not available. Please enter a different string."**

This indefinier is bundle id of my application, and I did not change it.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this problem next way:

- remove all provision profiles which links with problem project (using «iPhone Configuration Utility»)
- generate new provision profile on developer.apple.com
- download and install this provision profile (and updated expired provision profiles) on local computer
- choose new provision in "Code Signing Identity"
- build project

Comment: You can also delete them without iPhone Configuration Utility by going to `"~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"` in Finder and delete the profiles from there.

Comment: @nihilvex you fixed my problem, I delete all provisioning with terminal cd `cd  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and write `rm *` and works fine. Notes: No paste path on terminal write or maybe not found for spaces.